# listing macro variable's values with prefix in a procedure

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Let's say I create a macro variable.

`%let par = var1 var2 var3;`

Now I want to use those values in a procedure like this

`proc score data=test type=parms score=par out=score; 
 var W_var1 W_var2 W_var3;
 run;`

For example, if var1=age then I want to list W_age in the var statement. I tried `var W_&par;` but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me with a simple solution here? Big thanks!!

Comment: For a utility macro that can add prefixes, suffixes, and delimiters, see Richard DeVenezia's macro %seplist. http://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/macros/index.php?m=seplist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a macro to resolve this problem.

The macro gets each parameter from macro variable and adds to it some prefix.

```
%macro list_with_prefix(string, prefix);
    %local i;
    %let i = 1;
    %do %until(%scan(&string., &i., %str( )) = );
        &prefix.%scan(&string., &i., %str( ))
        %let i = %eval(&i. + 1);
    %end;
%mend;

%let par = var1 var2 var3;

proc score data=test type=parms score=par out=score; 
    var %list_with_prefix(&par, W_);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular express:

```
%let par = var1 var2 var3;
%let new_par=%sysfunc(prxchange(s/(\w+)/W_$1/,-1,&par));
%put &new_par;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using the `TRANWRD()` function.

```
%let par = var1 var2 var3;
%let new_par=W_%sysfunc(tranwrd(&par,%str( ),%str( W_)));
%put &new_par;
```

But you do need to make sure your parameter doesn't have multiple spaces between words.  So either run this first or nest it into the statement above.

```
%let par=%sysfunc(compbl(&par));
```